# Can you call API on seperate threads that dont return Objects?

Tags: php

I use PHP which lacks native threading support, so I use Pthreads.

Anyways, the #1 rule of threading is to never pass objects to it, or if you must, sterilize it before hand to prevent segment faults. So my question is, is it ok to call APIs from your main thread if it does not return objects? Further more, if you pass sterilized objects and then unsterilize it, can you use the objects functions on the separate thread (and will that function execute on the main thread?)?